# Converting rows to proper dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this types of rows

```
start=2019-11-02T00:00:00&end=2019-11-03T00:00:00&step=1L
source=B&select=mean&step=5K&format=2&start=2019-11-02T00
```

I want to change this to proper csv format in this way

```
start,end,step,source,select,format
2019-11-02T00:00:00,2019-11-03T00:00:00,1L,,,
2019-11-02T00,,5K,B,mean,2
```

As you can see that, first rows doesnt have source,select and format, so there is no values in this csv for that row. Similary, there is Nan for second row because there is no values for it.

How Can I do this in pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert file to one column `DataFrame` with some sep not exist in data first by [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

temp="""start=2019-11-02T00:00:00&end=2019-11-03T00:00:00&step=1L
source=B&select=mean&step=5K&format=2&start=2019-11-02T00"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";", names=['data'])

print (df)
                                                data
0  start=2019-11-02T00:00:00&end=2019-11-03T00:00...
1  source=B&select=mean&step=5K&format=2&start=20...
```

Then create list of dictionaries in list comprehension and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = [dict([y.split('=') for y in x.split('&')]) for x in df['data']]

df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df)
                 start                  end step source select format
0  2019-11-02T00:00:00  2019-11-03T00:00:00   1L    NaN    NaN    NaN
1        2019-11-02T00                  NaN   5K      B   mean      2
```

Last write to file by [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```
df.to_csv('filename1.csv', index=False)
```